# Unity3D: The components behind a collider is not Clickable

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a mobile app,in which there is a `UIGrid` which contains 'n' number of clickable images. And over that Grid there is `collider` which is used for scrolling purpose. Now the problem is,the scrolling only works, but not the images in the grid. When i hide `collider` then i can click those images in the `Grid`.
Can anyone help to fix this.
Cheers

Comment: You could also try setting the layers and only allowing touches to be registered on a certain layer

Answer (score 0):

In the Unity editor, select the collider you made, and change the "z" position to less than of the images, which would place it behind them.